# C# Delete Instance of Class?

Tags: c#, class, instance

I am sort of new to C# and I have a quick question about instances of classes.
I was told that using only "null"on an instance of a class isn't enough to delete an entire instance and all it's resources, such as pointers, etc. So I have:
`ClassHere myClass = new ClassHere()` and `myClass = null`

I really must be thinking about this too hard... I'll give an example as to figure out how exactly the GC works.

Let's say we have 3 instances: x1, x2, x3. Each instance would be mapped to a variable: `ClassHere myClass = new ClassHere()` except you'd have x1, x2 and x3 instead of myClass.

Then say instances x2 and x3 make some sort of reference to x1. Let's say that x1 does nothing after being referenced by x2 and x3. The GC would only pick up x1 after x2's, and x3's references of x1 would be removed, correct?

If it picks it up even with those references. How would the GC know whether or not I actually need instance x1 which is referenced by x2 and x3 instead of deleting it?

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It's C#, don't worry at all about "deleting" your class and freeing up memory/pointers. The GC does all that for you.

Comment: "Resources" refers to unmanaged resources, i.e. operating system handles, not memory. If all you are doing is allocating memory for objects the GC will take care of it automatically.

Comment: You can manually call GC.collect() but it's not recommended because c# does it for you. But if you want to you can, you're just telling the compiler to collect the garbage at this exact location because you know what you are doing( Smarter than the computer)

Comment: Rather, I want to remove any reference to the instance, so GC picks it up. That's what I am getting at.

Comment: Probably a more relevant question - why do you want to "delete" the instance so it can be collected?  Are you running out of memory?  Does it have security implications if the class is resident in memory?  Does the class contain resources that need to be released?  There are solutions to each problem.

Comment: E.g. let's say an instance of a class represents an instance of an object in a game. That instance is no longer needed. Remove instance.

Rather "why" doesn't matter, but "how"...

Comment: C# was designed to avoid manual management. There is simply no mechanism like "Remove instance". That is, because is is not needed. And the guys were busy implementing other, important, things.

Comment: In case you desperately crave such a mechanism, I recommend C++ or Delphi/Pascal. Both of these have explicit destructors. That leaves you with references to invalid objects ("dangling pointer") if called too early.

Comment: Well, it's not removing it myself. It's removing reference to said instance, so the instance falls out of scope. Once it falls out of scope, then the GC will pick it up, right? So, e.g. you "could" be using it and at some point decide, it's not longer needed. You would then need to remove any reference before the GC picks it up.

That's what I am going for. Remove all references, so the GC picks up the instance. Wouldn't you need to do that? If not, wouldn't it always be in scope by whatever is holding reference to said instance?

Comment: Check out reachability section of the Wikipedia article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the only way to destroy a **class** is to remove it from your source tree :D You can, though destroy **instances** of a class.

Unlike C++, C# doesn't have deterministic destructors. An object instance becomes *eligible* for garbage collection when the object instance becomes unreachable. That can happen by virtue of

- all references to it being released (e.g., variable going out of scope), or
- all references to it being themselves unreachable (e.g., the object instance is references in a collection, and the collection is itself unreachable.

When and if an object instance is garbage-collected depends on memory/resource pressure within the app domain (process). When the app domain ends, though, everything is garbage collected.

Usually you want to make things that matter implement `IDisposable`, so non-managed resources held can be deterministically released via `using` blocks and the like.

This is a simplistic answer, but the gist of it is: don't sweat it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been asking. D: I don't want to remove the class itself, just an instance of the class. The post says that clearly.

So how would I go about using the IDisposable method? Will it remove any resources within the instance being removed?

Comment: You only need to use IDisposable with unmanaged resources like Nicholas says.  From your code it looks like you are dealing with a managed resource (Managed means the garbage collector takes care of it).  Unless you have left out some information about why you are trying to free this memory, you are thinking too hard about this.

Comment: Simply trying to get rid of unnecessary resources. I don't really "have anything". Just curious as to how.

Comment: That's one great thing about managed code, you really don't need to worry about it, let the GC do it's thing, that's exactly why it's there =)

Comment: Rephrased main question... let's see if I can figure this GC thing out.

Comment: Re-read my answer and read this link about how it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx. Your object instances become *eligible* for GC when they become unreachable by your code: you could a gigantic, enormous and interconnected object graph and it remains reachable so long as there is a single reference to one of the object in the graph by your executing code. When that get set to `null` or it goes out of scope, that graph becomes unreachable and eligible for GC. Whether it ever *gets* GC'd is another question entirely. But *you* don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Any of your managed resources you don't need to worry about "deleting".  The Garbage Collector will take care of this for you.  You only need to worry about cleanup in the case where you are using unmanaged resources(Which I'm assuming you aren't as you don't mention it).

You do not need to null out variables for the GC to collect it.

Here's a link I found on a related stackoverflow question that might help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx

Comment: Well, I still need to dereference any resources I am not using for the GC to pick it up right? That's my goal here.

Comment: If I don't need to, how does the GC know I am not using an instance of a class and when to delete it??

Comment: Think the other way round: You do not need to do something for the GC. If some instance _happens to fall out of scope_, the GC will collect it. It will fall out of scope eventually, if you don't need it any more.

Comment: The MS CLR/.Net garbage collector uses a mark-and-sweep algorithm. Other implementations (e.g., Mono) could conceivable use reference counting or other approaches. Some details on garbage collection can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

Comment: You should create and use instances exactly when you need them and in a fixed scope - inside a method, class, etc. and as things fall out of scope, they'll be marked to collect.  If on the other hand everything is stored in static members everywhere in your app, they'll never disappear.  In your example above, it looks like you're creating that instance as a local variable inside a method perhaps?  In that case, at the end of the method, assuming that instance was not stored anywhere else, there should be no more references to it.  No need to do anything more.

Comment: I know, the GC will collect it when it's out of scope, but what can I do to PUT it instance out of scope? How could I remove all references of an instance so that instance falls out of scope for the GC to pickup?

Comment: You can DESIGN it to fall out of scope at the correct time.  Meaning don't have a global type variable if you only need it within a method. Define it in the method, and when the method exits, it will go out of scope.  If the code is designed to where it won't ever make another call that requires your variable, the GC will know that and flag it to be collected.

Answer (score -1):

If the code is running on a server GC isn't going to deallocate the object- unless you restart the server every half hour- seems like a legitimate question to me... I had a similar problem- detecting when a user shuts the browser as opposed to manually logging off the website- my solution was to create an instance for user with a timer and a flag that is set to true via ajax and reset to false by server side timer. But there was a potential for memory leaks- since there was no guarantee instance of the user was being deallocated when they would be automatically logged off.

So I create a class user outside webservice like this and instantiated a list of type user:

```
 class WebService{
  public static List<user> UserLoglist = new List<user>();//list of logged in users

 [WebMethod(Description = "Per session Hit Counter", EnableSession = true)]
public void  ClnUpdateFlag(string un)//gets called via ajax
{//Updates the flags i

    //update users status
    WebService.UserLoglist.Find(y => y.username == un).isLoggedin = true;
}
    }
public class user
{
    public string username;
    public System.Timers.Timer timScheduledTask = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public bool isLoggedin = true;
    public  user(string puser)
    {
        username = puser;

        setimer(); //set server side timer
    }
    void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     ...
  if (isLoggedin)// window is still open
          isLoggedin = false;
   else// user closed the window
      {
         ...

          WebService.UserLoglist.RemoveAll(x => x.username == username);// instance is deleted here

   ...

      } 
      }
    }

    void setimer()
    {
        timScheduledTask.Interval = 3000;
        timScheduledTask.Enabled = true;
         timScheduledTask.Start(); 
        timScheduledTask.Elapsed +=
        new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
    }
 }
```

}

```
    class login{

   ...
    public void Logon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserEmail.Text, UserPass.Text)){
        ...
         WebService.UserLoglist.Add(new user(UserEmail.Text));// instance of the user is instantiated here
        }
   ...
   }
 }
```